# Javascript Regular Expression Combine Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I have two expressions that I would like to combine as well as fix the second expression. The expressions are listed bellow. The input for the script is bellow.

```
Value/1.2 (Value; And Value Value Value 2_4_6) ValueAgain/3.5.7 (Value, Value Value) Value/4.6.8 Value/5.7.9
```

1. `/\(.*?\)/` (Gets all text outside of parenthesis)
2. `/\s*([\w]+?)\/([\d\w\W]+?)(\s+|\z)/g` (Splits `Value/1.2.b` into and array that equals this `['Value', '1.2.b']`)

With these expressions I currently run the following script.

```
var a = 'Value/1.2 (Value; And Value Value Value 2_4_6) ValueAgain/3.5.7 (Value, Value Value) Value/4.6.8 Value/5.7.9', b = /\s*([\w]+?)\/([\d\w\W]+?)(\s+|\z)/g, c = a.split(/\(.*?\)/);
console.log(a, c);
for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    console.log('Exec: ', b.exec(c[i]), ' Split: ', c[i].split(b));
}
```

This script logs are bellow.

```
Value/1.2 (Value; And Value Value Value 2_4_6) ValueAgain/3.5.7 (Value, Value Value) Value/4.6.8 Value/5.7.9 ["Value/1.2 ", " ValueAgain/3.5.7 ", " Value/4.6.8 Value/5.7.9"]
Exec:  ["Value/1.2 ", "Value", "1.2", " "]  Split:  ["", "Value", "1.2", " ", ""]
Exec:  ["n/3.5.7 ", "n", "3.5.7", " "]  Split:  ["", "ValueAgain", "3.5.7", " ", ""]
Exec:  null  Split:  ["", "Value", "4.6.8", " ", "Value/5.7.9"]
```

- The second expression should also parse and split all the forward slash's but in the last log statement its still has not parsed "`Value/5.7.9`".
- As I had mentioned I would also like to combine these statements into one if that is possible.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @hwnd The output should be an array that looks like this ['Value', '1.2', 'ValueAgain', '3.5.7', 'Value', '4.6.8', 'Value', '5.7.9']

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two regular expressions together by converting them to strings and constructing a new one. For example:

```
var rega = /(.*?)/,
    regb = /(^[>]+)/,

regc = new RegExp
(
    rega.toString().toString().slice(1, -1) +
    regb.toString().toString().slice(1, -1),
    'g'
);
```

Would result in `regc` being `/(.*?)(^[>]+)/g`.